# How to get ajax slider control value in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I can't get the slider control current value

```
<asp:SliderExtender ID="TextBox1_SliderExtender" runat="server" BoundControlID="Label2"
Enabled="True" EnableHandleAnimation="True" Length="170" Maximum="10000" 
Minimum="0" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</asp:SliderExtender>


var PA = M.Items.Where(c => c.Item_Price < Convert.ToDecimal( Label2.Text) || 
 c.Item_Price_After_Sale < Convert.ToDecimal(Label2.Text) || c.Item_Price == 
 Convert.ToDecimal(Label2.Text) || c.Item_Price_After_Sale == Convert.ToDecimal(Label2.Text));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> When a value is chosen using the Slider, it is automatically persisted
>   during full or partial postbacks. The developer can continue to
>   reference the asp:TextBox to get and set the Slider's value.

So you would retrieve the text from TextBox1 just as you would normally:

```
string value = TextBox1.Text;
```

or

```
string value = Request.Form["TextBox1 "].ToString();
```

Looks like you were trying to use Label2 instead.